# How do I get a consecutive number generator?

Tags: c#

I am making a program that draws randomly generated sizes of circles where you click.  If you move your mouse will clicking the left button it will leave of trail of randomly sized circles.

I however want these circles, when you move the mouse, to get bigger than smaller. For example start with a size 20 circle than increase by one so the next circle will be 21 than 22 than 23 ect.  Than when it reaches 80 turn it around and go 80, 79,78,77,76 ect.

This is the code for the randomly genereated circle.

I have tried a couple different ways but am only a learner.  Thank you for any help that you can give.

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();

            int width = this.ClientSize.Width;
            int length = this.ClientSize.Height;
            Graphics paper = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            Pen pen = new Pen(colorDialog1.Color, 2);

            int sizeCircle = rand.Next(20, 80);

            int mouseX = e.X - (sizeCircle/2) ;
            int mouseY = e.Y - (sizeCircle/2) ;

            paper.DrawEllipse(pen, mouseX, mouseY, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
```

Comment: your question is not clear enough, you want to assign consecutive numbers instead for random to `sizeCircle` am i right?

Comment: Yes.  Instead of every next number being random.  I want every next number to be one up from the last.  Than when it reaches 80 turn around and make the next number be less than the one before it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this...

Declare your size variable outside the event handler so you can keep track of its value..

```
bool enlarge = true; // flag to identitify if the size should enlarge or not
int circle_size = 10; // initial size
int circle_size_change = 5; // size value change
int max_size = 80; // max size
int min_size = 10; // min size
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int width = this.ClientSize.Width;
        int length = this.ClientSize.Height;
        Graphics paper = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(colorDialog1.Color, 2);

        if(enlarge)
        { 
           if(circle_size + circle_size_change > max_size)
           {
               enlarge = false;
           }
        }
        else
        {
           if(circle_size - circle_size_change < min_size)
           {
               enlarge = true;      
           }
        }

        circle_size = enlarge ? circle_size + circle_size_change : circle_size - circle_size_change;

        int mouseX = e.X - (circle_size/2) ;
        int mouseY = e.Y - (circle_size/2) ;

        paper.DrawEllipse(pen, mouseX, mouseY, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
```